# Reorder Stacked barchart variables

Tags: r

I'm a beginner with R and I can't find a solution to a very easy problem apparently. I am creating a stacked bar chart but the variables stacked in each bar are in a different order from the one I'd like to get. I tried different solutions here but none has worked so far.

I have created this data set in excel

```
# A tibble: 5 x 11
  Company            Q12019 Q22019 Q32019 Q42019 Q12020 Q22020 Q32020 Q42020 Q12021 Q22021
  <chr>               <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 TSMC                  481    492    505    527    541    515    539    556    545    529
2 Samsung Electroni~    191    180    185    178    159    188    174    164    174    173
3 Globalfoundries        84     87     83     80     77     74     70     66     55     61
4 UMC                    72     75     67     68     74     73     70     69     71     72
5 Other                 172    166    160    147    149    150    147    145    155    165
```

Then I gathered the Quarters data and uncounted the values to get the barchart.

```
 A tibble: 10,000 x 2
   Company Quarter
   <chr>   <chr>  
 1 TSMC    Q12019 
 2 TSMC    Q12019 
 3 TSMC    Q12019 
 4 TSMC    Q12019 
 5 TSMC    Q12019 
 6 TSMC    Q12019 
 7 TSMC    Q12019 
 8 TSMC    Q12019 
 9 TSMC    Q12019 
10 TSMC    Q12019 
# ... with 9,990 more rows
```

Now when I created the bar chart

```
Newdata %>%
  ggplot(aes(Quarter,fill=Company))+
  geom_bar()
```

I get this graph with the "Company" values stacked in the order "Globalfoundries", "other", "Samsung Electronics", "TSMC", "UMC"

[stacked bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMiHI.jpg)

But would like to change the order of the "company" variables putting "Other" on top, "UMC" second, and leaving the others as they are right below. Can anyone suggest a way to do it?

Comment: https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/267-reorder-a-variable-in-ggplot2.html

Comment: I tried this but there isn't the kind of graph I'm trying to obtain, so these methods didn't work. Or maybe I didn't apply them correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change `Company` to a factor instead of a character field, and then designate the preferred order yourself.

```
Newdata$Company <- factor(Newdata$Company, levels= c('Other','UMC', 'Globalfoundries', 'Samsung Electronics','TSMC'))
```

Run this on your `Newdata` and recreate your `ggplot` and the stack order should be correct.

Comment: Thanks! That worked perfectly. And thanks also for the insight.

Comment: Glad to help - this is something you will probably encounter with ggplot again in the future.  Feel free to accept answer

Comment: Thanks again. I have to say, I do not understand completely the logic behind this though. Why the variable turned into factor can be rearranged while as a character column it can't?

Comment: It appears ggplot automatically orders character columns alphabetically.  As a factor, you get to determine the order you want them in.  It seems like you should be able to determine the order of a character column, but I haven't seen that before in response to this type of problem.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot for your help.